# Jetpack Compose Dropdown

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have this dropdown, but it doesn't fill all the screen width despite the Modifier.fillMaxWidth().

The main area in the top app bar is stretched across the width of the screen and when I click on it, I expect the dropdown to expand with the same width as my Top App Bar. But the expanded dropdown is narrower.

How can I change it for it to fill max screen width?

````
fun DropdownChildren(
    items: List<ChildUiModel>,
    chosenChild: ChildUiModel?,
    onChildChosen: (ChildUiModel) -> Unit
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(onClick = { expanded = true }),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
            ChildrenDropdownMenuItem(
                imageUrl = chosenChild?.profileImage?: "https://c8.alamy.com/comp/TBRA08/many-children-on-frame-border-illustration-TBRA08.jpg",
                    text = chosenChild?.name?: stringResource(id = R.string.all_children),
                    chosen = false)

        }

        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .requiredSizeIn(maxHeight = 500.dp)
        ) {
            items.forEachIndexed { index, child ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = if (child.id == chosenChild?.id) appColors.secondary else appColors.primary),
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = false
                        selectedIndex = index
                        onChildChosen(items[selectedIndex])
                }) {
                    ChildrenDropdownMenuItem(
                        imageUrl = if (child.profileImage == null)
                            "https://pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/2793494581535699799-512.png"
                        else child.profileImage?: "https://pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/2793494581535699799-512.png",
                        text = child.name,
                        chosen = child.id == chosenChild?.id)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildrenDropdownMenuItem(
    imageUrl: String,
    text: String,
    chosen: Boolean
){
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically){
        Avatar(url = imageUrl)
        Text(text = text,
            style = AppTheme.typography.h4,
            color = if (chosen) appColors.primary else appColors.secondary)
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score -2):

Read the source code of DropdownMenu, the max with is hard coded, you can copy the source code, set the width to a value you prefer.

Comment: Can you please specify what exactly I should change in the source code? I've copied it, tried playing around with hard coded widths and offsets and paddings, but nothing worked. Whatever I change, it still has this empty space on the right.